# ASP.NET Razor Entity Framework using Case statement against the model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying to find the correct way to do this and I'd appreciate some direction in how to do it. I have a scaffolded entity framework controller with views, and multiple items in my model that refer back to an enum:

```
public enum JobStatus
{
    NotStarted, InProgress, AwaitingReboot, Completed
}

public class Job
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string EngineerName { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }

    public JobStatus? OverallJobStatus { get; set; }

    public JobStatus? WindowsUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? MicrosoftUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? ExchangeUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? FirmwareUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? SymantecSEPMUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? SymantecClientsUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? BackupSoftwareUpdateCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? BackupManualCheckCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? EventViewerCheckCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? DiskDefragCompleted { get; set; }
    public JobStatus? RecreateSBSMonitoring { get; set; }
```

The index.cshtml is referencing this as (here is one for example):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExchangeUpdateCompleted)
```

This all works fine, and in the relevant columns per row I get the job status of NotStarted or AwaitingReboot etc.

I have four span classes that represent a bootstrap glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off red"></span>
```

What I want to do, instead of displaying NotStarted or AwaitingReboot etc I want to display the span class instead.

I'd assume this would require a switch/case statement. Where would the proper place be for this in an MVC framework? I'd assume the most efficient way to do this would be a function of some sort where I pass the jobstatus and it outputs the correct span class? Any direction with a code example would be appreciated.

Based on this how would I display this in the actual code

Comment: Have you thought of using a `DisplayTemplate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using a display template.

First create the folder `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` and in there add a view called `JobStatus.cshtml` (i.e. the name matched the type.) In that view, put the logic for determining the HTML you want to output. For example:

```
@model QuartelyMaintenance.Models.JobStatus

@{
    string icon = "ok";
    string colour = "green";

    switch (Model)
    {
        case QuartelyMaintenance.Models.NotStarted:
            icon = "star";
            colour = "red";
            break;
        case QuartelyMaintenance.Models.AwaitingReboot :
            icon = "off";
            colour = "green";
            break;
    }
}
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-@icon @colour"></span>
```

Now you can use it like you do normally and MVC will pick up this template:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExchangeUpdateCompleted)
```

Comment: This looks excellent if I can do it like this, but I'm struggling to get this working, I get the the name 'JobStatus' Does not exist in the current context. I have @model QuartelyMaintenance.Models.JobStatus in the root of the file

Comment: I've change to match your namespace. Use the namespace in the case statement too.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a static method in your model class:

```
public static string GetHtmlForJobStatus(JobStatus status)
{
    switch(status)
    {
        case JobStatus.Completed:
        {
            return @"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green"></span>"
        }
        case JobStatus.Completed:
        {
            return @"<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></span>"
        }

        // the rest of your cases
    }
}
```

Then, in your view you can just call that for each one:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.GetHtmlForJobStatus(Model.ExchangeUpdateCompleted))
```

Comment: If you return `MvcHtmlString` instead of string then you won't need to use `Html.Raw` in the view. Though personally I like to avoid putting HTML in code like this, hence why I prefer DisplayTemplates.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I went back and forth on returning string or HtmlString.  I figured it's about the same amount of code either way, and both approaches are fairly clear.

Comment: @DavidG I agree with your DisplayTemplate approach.  It's probably better to bury that switch as deeply as possible anyway - they're ugly.

Comment: Wasn't just the amount of code, it was more the simplicity of the view. Anyway, this approach isn't wrong per se. You could also use attributes on the enum and pick them out in the display template. A little overkill probably, but fun to code up!

Comment: PS you can still have +1 from me :)

Comment: @DavidG Haha thank you - you get +1 from me as well =)  The approach in your answer definitely results in a cleaner view.